# How does the charge accumulate inside a parallel plate capacitor?

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance

I couldn't properly understand, how is it so that if I have a parallel plate capacitor, in which one plate has $+Q$ charge and another has $-Q$ charge then all the charge on the first plate will accumulate on that side where it is facing the other plate, and same for the second plate i.e. it will accumulate on the side where it is facing the first plate.

My Teacher was teaching, the class about parallel plate capacitors and he just, told it (the charge distribution I described above) will be so. But I couldn't understand how or why will the charges accumulate on just 1 face of each plate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The opposite charge between the plates attract each other so will try and be as close together as possible. The closest location on a plate to the other plate is on the side of the plate facing the other plate.

Comment: Thanks I was thinking the same thing just a second ago, but was not sure